# jQuery: How to access <span> value attribute in Firefox?

Tags: jquery

This code is working in IE and not in Firefox.
Help me

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() { alert($('#hi').val()); });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='hi'value='10'>This is my name</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want the HTML code inside `<span></span>`:

```
$('#hi').html()
```

If you want the value of the attribute named `value`:

```
$('#hi').attr('value')
```

See the jQuery documentation for [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), and [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for more details.

Comment: Yeah... I think `.val()` is only for actual form elements.

Comment: @Mark: Exactly. From jQuery documentation: "primarily used to get the values of form elements." From jQuery 1.4.4 source code: `return (elem.value || "").replace(rreturn, "");` It seems that Firefox only supports `.value` on form elements.

Answer (score 1):

you would use

```
$('#hi').attr('attr_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

The val() method looks for for the an attribute named 'value' on the selector.

eg.

```
<input type='text' id='hi' value='value' />
```

In a span element, you would typically not use value, but have text inside the element.

like:

```
  <span id='hi'>text here</span>
```

Use $("#hi").text();  to retrieve that text